# Disproportionate stratified sampling in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sampling

How can I randomly select one row from each group (column `Name`) in the following dataframe:

```
   Distance   Name  Time  Order
1        16   John     5      0
4        31   John     9      1
0        23   Kate     3      0
3        15   Kate     7      1
2        32  Peter     2      0
5        26  Peter     4      1
```

Expected result:

```
Distance   Name  Time  Order

4        31   John     9      1
0        23   Kate     3      0
2        32  Peter     2      0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Name` col and apply  [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

```
df.groupby('Name',as_index=False).apply(lambda x:x.sample()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    Distance   Name  Time  Order
0        31   John     9      1
1        15   Kate     7      1
2        32  Peter     2      0
```

Comment: Nice one :) +1. I just has one thought. If we `sample` the whole dataframe and `groupby.head` such as this `df.sample(df.shape[0]).groupby('Name').head(1)` to avoid using `apply`. Would it be any difference? I really don't remember the theory of randomness.

Comment: @AndyL. Nice suggestion , That would be little faster, also Mykola Zotko has a good suggestion if one is looking for performance.

Comment: hah, I totally missed his solution until you mentioned it. I just upvoted his as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle all samples using, for example, the `numpy` function `random.permutation`. Then `groupby` by `Name` and take N first rows from each group:

```
df.iloc[np.random.permutation(len(df))].groupby('Name').head(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achive that using `unique`

```
df['Name'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the dataframe:

```
df.sample(frac=1)
```

And then drop duplicated rows:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name')



   Distance   Name  Time  Order
1        16   John     5      0
0        23   Kate     3      0
2        32  Peter     2      0
```

> This should help, but this not random choice, it keeps the first

Answer (score 0):

How about using [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

like this,

Import your provided data,

```
df=pd.read_csv('random_data.csv', header=0)
```

which looks like this,

```
Distance  Name  Time  Order
1        16  John     5      0
4         3  John     9      1
0        23  Kate     3      0
3        15  Kate     7      1
```

then get a random column name,

```
colname = df.columns[random.randint(1, 3)]
```

and below it selected 'Name',

```
   print(df[colname])
1    John
4    John
0    Kate
3    Kate
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Of course I could have condensed this to,

```
print(df[df.columns[random.randint(1, 3)]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Distance': [16, 31, 23, 15, 32, 26],
        'Name': ['John', 'John', 'Kate', 'Kate', 'Peter', 'Peter'],
        'Time': [5, 9, 3, 7, 2, 4],
        'Order': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    },
    index=[1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 5],
)
```

```py
df.groupby('Name').sample(n=1)
```